# My page is auto loading when I click on any element of a form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have some issues with CodeIgniter `form_open()` method. While using it, if I click anything on form  my page automatically reload the current page. What can be the solution?

Comment: you're gonna have to post some code for us to help

Comment: If you're clicking the submit button and your form's `action` attribute is empty or set to current page, you're gonna get the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Please post your code, we can not guess what's going on.

Comment: has nothing to do with `form_open` which basically just creates a `<form>` tag. Show all relevant code. See [mcve]

Comment: Test basic example from docs.

Comment: thanks for the response. i have sorted out the problem. The problem occurred because i used wrong jquery.